# Recursively reversing a linkedlist with only two pointers returns?

Tags: java, pointers, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to recursively reverse a linkedlist with "only" two pointers. In reality, each recursive call temporarily makes a third pointer to assist it. I have a certain algorithm I am trying to make that follows [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Zcf6iKApJc). While going up the stack, the program works fine, but as the program goes down the stack my returns don't seem to do anything:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      ListNode head = new ListNode("hello", null);
      head = new ListNode("foo", head);
      head = new ListNode("boo", head);
      head = new ListNode("nonsense", head);
      head = new ListNode("computer",
         new ListNode("science",
         new ListNode("java",
         new ListNode("coffee", head))));
//head is [computer, science, java, coffee, nonsense, boo, foo, hello]

System.out.print("recur with 2 pointers: \t\t\t\t");
      head = recurTwoPointers(null, head);
      print(head);
```

```
public static ListNode recurTwoPointers(ListNode prev, ListNode head)
   {
      if(head == null){
         return head;
      }
      ListNode next = head.getNext();
      head.setNext(prev);
      recurTwoPointers(head, next);
      return next;
   }
```

I've tried every combination of returns I can think of. A the program goes down the stack, it seems to undo what its done, and values get lost. In the end, I end up only returning

```
[science, computer]
```

instead of

```
[hello, foo, boo, nonsense, coffee, java, science, computer]
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a list of length N:

If N=1, return the unmodified list.

Else, remove and save the first item in the list, then reverse the remaining list of length N-1. Return the reversed list after adding the saved element to the end.

Comment: `List.add(List.removeFirst())`?

Comment: ```list.add(reverse(list.removeFirst()))```

Comment: Your first reference is the first element. The second reference is `reverse(list.getNext())`. The element after first is now at the end of the reversed portion. Using first you can set the end of the reversed portion to the first element.

Comment: None of these help because they are using methods and algorithms I cant use. All I need help on is how to return my reversed list after all the stack of recursive calls? recurTwoPointers gets called 10 times, and the prev pointer contains the reversed node and head is null - how do I return that information as it goes down the stack

Comment: What "methods and algorithms" are you talking about? There is nothing wrong with these answers. The problem is that you're too attached to your buggy code.

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy Unfortunately, that's not true. I just discovered the answer: my return calls for recurTwoPointers() wasn't being stored anywhere, so they were getting lost. all I had to do was "next = recurTwoPointers()" and return next

Comment: @OptimalOG what methods can't you use? Why didn't you include it in your question?

Comment: @KnowNoTrend Sorry, should've added this: I'm using the CollegeBoard's ListNode class, which only has getters and setters for values and nodes

Comment: Getters and setters? Surely you can add and remove the last node?

Comment: @KnowNoTrend Are you talking about reverse() ? That is the recursive method you are defining here... also the primary concept being taught.